# How to make ASP.NET read more then one file ini and lines

Tags: javascript, html

I want make website ASP.NET to make reads files in the format of ini, and the files have multiple ID like in photo, and inside the file. I want the code to read the line Online = 0 and when it becomes Online = 1, this appears on the site , and i want write in home page Online [value of ini] , thanks
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTr2K.png)